# genetic algorithm cross over

Tags: genetic-algorithm

so if I use the following to implement crossover in a genetic algorithm:

```
Input: Two strings of n bits x and y
Output: Two strings of n bits x' and y'
```

and apply the crossover operator like this:

A crossover site is selected at random (with equal probability) that divides each string into two sub-strings of non-zero length:

```
x = [x1, x2];
y = [y1, y2]
```

with:

```
x1.length = y1.length
```

The outputs are generated as:

```
x' = [x1, y2]
y' = [y1, x2]
```

Given that you start with

```
(x1, y1) = ((1 0 1 0) (1 1 1 1))
```

specify which `4 bit strings` are possible values obtained through crossover alone.

So is this right?

```
0 1 0 1
```

I think its right just adding them together but Im a bit lost on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding them together is wrong.

A genome length of 4 implies there 3 possible [crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_%28genetic_algorithm%29) points (non zero length). These are between each of the 4 bits.

If you select a crossover point of 2, and inputs of:

(**1010**) (*1111*) -- x & y --

your resulting strings are:

(**10**.*11*) -- first 2 of x & last 2 of y.

(*11*.**10**) -- first 2 of y & last 2 of x.

Therefore it is easy to figure out the other 2 permutations (crossover points 1 & 3).

I suspect this is homework, so ill not do it all for you :)

Comment: oh i see I was thinking about multiplying the two things together not breaking them apart that was my disconnect there thanks